# How to load XML (with xslt) generated by javascript into an IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, xslt, iframe

I'm generating some simple XML via javascript, and then using doc.open, doc.write, and doc.close to write the xml into an iframe.

My problem is that in the iframe, it is not being rendered properly. It's as if the xslt renderer is not kicking into gear and it tries to render as html(just showing the text node values).

The xml itself is proper and when pasted in an xml file and loaded, renders properly with the xslt.

Is it a matter of somehow telling the browser what data type the generated xml is (and how would i do that?) or is there a way to kick it into xslt rendering mode?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the generated XML (with stylesheet processing-instruction)? And how you put it into the iframe? Also what browser are you using?

Comment: I serialize the xml dom via:
function xml2Str(xmlNode) {
   try {
      // Gecko- and Webkit-based browsers (Firefox, Chrome), Opera.
      return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlNode);
  }
  catch (e) {
     try {
        // Internet Explorer.
        return xmlNode.xml;
     }
     catch (e) {  
        //Other browsers without XML Serializer
        alert('Xmlserializer not supported');
     }
   }
   return false;
}

Comment: then i load it into the iframe via:
doc = null;
doc = document.getElementById('ifrm').contentDocument;
if(doc == undefined || doc == null)
{
 doc = document.getElementById('ifrm').contentWindow.document;
}
doc.open();
doc.write(xml2Str(myXml));
doc.close();

Comment: At the moment, I can get the desired result via changing the iframe src to a dynamic page the reflects back the xml I pass it via url encoding, however, i'd like to achieve the same results without relying on a server side technology.

Comment: As for browser, using both IE and firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best approach it would be to run the transformation with javascript and then to add result to DOM. As example, from http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml=loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
xsl=loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
  }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If supported, data URL can be handy.

```
iframe.src = 'data:text/xml,' + encodeURI('<x m="l"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the doctype for the output: http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=763